# Deploy an application on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment

I have created an application for iPhone on my MAC. Now, I got to pass files read for deployment to the tester and he will perform the testing on real device. I have never deployed on iPhone so don't know the executables.

In my Xcode nothing related to the device info or developer's account is added. Device is not in my hands. For testing on live device we need certificate, iPhone device details & setup in the Xcode & all. [Deploying iPhone app on real device](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

Can I just send the files to the tester & rest all he can manage ? If so, what files do I need to send him (executable) so he can deploy the app on iPhone. If this is not possible, then what and how do I need to setup to provide him the executables so he can test at his end.

Can you please guide me how to mange this and send the executables to deploy on iPhone. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you don one thing . Take UDIDs of the devices which the are going to install the app. then add those UDIDs to your developer provisioning profile and configour that profile with your application and build the project and create .iPA of the app and give it to him./her for testing via testflight or Dropbox . it would  be easy for them for installation later. Hope this can be useful and hope this is what u are looking for . If not let me know in detail\

Comment: @Adi, My developer account is of Free - so I can't submit apps to the store. Can I still add the UDIDs in my profile and will it work as you are mentioning ? I am a developer so why would I have to pay $99/- yearly for their apps. Also do I have to take are of the certificates -I believe that also they should provide me, right ?

Comment: Listen, I am also an developer . What i do. I just ask to client to provide me the access to their apple developer account. I go to member center add the UDID's, generates provisioning profile, download it and configour it with my app.Then i will build the app and generate  .iPA in my machine and give it to him for testing by mail or whatever. i Believe you could get the developer a/c access from client to do this.